# Постоянно ругается на метатег для дивайсов

Tags: html, meta

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no'>
```

Не знаю как исправить. Кажется испробовал все возможные варианты. Но все равно акцентирует внимание на это...

Comment: Ругается кто..?

Comment: В инструментах разработчика в браузере, вкладка Lighthous

Comment: Говорится что ```maximum-scale=1``` должно быть как минимум равно 5 и не рекомендуется ```user-scalable=no```